# Identity column Vs Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, primary-key, identity

How can we decide on to go with Identity column or Primary Key?

Comment: Or? Why not AND? The two things are not mutually exclusive. In fact, many people use an identity column as the primary key.

Comment: That depends on your scenario, really. Need more input. What is the specific issue you are facing? And like others said, you can use both on the same column.

Comment: The question is too vague. IDENTITY and PRIMARY KEY are unrelated features, neither mutually exclusive nor dependent on each other.

Answer (score 4):

The two concepts are not mutually exclusive. All combinations are possible:

- An identity column that is also a primary key,
- An identity column that is not a primary key,
- A primary key column that is not an identity,
- A column that is neither primary key nor identity

Note that an identity column is often used as a primary key as it is guaranteed to be unique, and it is usually in addition to the required schema fields, so it will not ahve to change if the schema changes.

Answer (score 2):

you use an Identity column when you need an auto increment. Period! Simple as that. Usually the identity column is a good candidate for a primary key.

Primary key is just a concept. Whats important behind the primary key is that it creates a CLUSTERED INDEX on the column so, in theory, you dont need the "Primary key" if you have a table with an unique clustered index.

I suggest you google and read about these two concepts, which are very importatn to understand

Comment: Primary key and clustered index are not equivalent. You can have clustered non PKs or non clustered PKs

Comment: yes, but what I meant is that when you create a primary key on a column, it creates a clustered index on that column and that's what's important

Comment: I never said they were equivalent...

Comment: The whole of your second paragraph seems to indicate that they are. The fact that it creates a clustered index by default if you don't specify any different is something to be aware of but is not an inherent property of primary keys.

Comment: where exactly? I wrote that by creating a PK, you automatically create a clustered index, and the clustered index is what really matters on the table.

Comment: The part `in theory, you dont need the "Primary key" if you have a table with a clustered index.` is nonsense as the two things are orthogonal concepts.

Comment: well thats what I think. CAn you tell me why you would need a primary key on a table if you have a clusterd unique index on it (is it because I didnt mention unique)?

Comment: Yes. A PK is basically equivalent to a unique index on non nullable columns but doesn't matter if that index is clustered or non clustered either.

Comment: ok thats fine, agree with that but you didnt answer my question. What would be the difference between having a PK and having a clustered unique index? Im not arguing with you, I just dont think there is any difference but if you say there is I would like to know :)

Comment: A key is not an index of any kind; a unique index isn't necessarily a key; a PK is not necessarily clustered. Those are three differences. Also the statement that creating a PK automatically creates a clustered index is wrong.

Comment: @sqlvogel, I know that a PK is not necessarily clustered and I wont even discuus your first 2 statments because they make no sense on the discussion. Also, creating a primary key DOES create a clustered index on the column, run a little test and you will see it.

Comment: @Diego "a PK is not necessarily clustered" QED. Therefore creating a primary key demonstrably does not mean a clustered index is always created on that key. If you genuinely don't understand the point of creating keys other than the one you actually clustered on (quote: "why you would need a primary key if you have a ... clustered index") then  this space is indeed too small to explain.

Comment: of course it does, test it! run create table test(id int primary key) and you will see that a clusterd index will be created on column id. Also, explain me one situation where you need a priamry key and you cannot solve an issue with an unique clusted index

Comment: You already told us (correctly) that not all primary keys are created as clustered indexes so what exactly are you trying to demonstrate now? There are a number of possible answers to your last question, including: wherever the key isn't the most efficient choice for a clustered index (e.g. due to key size or potential page splits/fragmentation) or wherever the chosen unique clustered index doesn't happen to qualify as a key (e.g. not minimal or non-null).

Comment: what Im trying to say is that I cant find a situation where a primary key couldnt be replaced by a unique clustered index (lets call UCI so I dont have to write it all the time) and by not finding it I can conclude that they are "the same". I'm not saying Im against PKs, Of course I use them, its much easier and intuitive than the UCI, BUT again, Im just looking for a situation where you can say: "in this case you cannot use a UCI, you absolutly need a PK".

Comment: That's very different to what you originally said though. It should suffice to say that indexes and keys are different things. Keys are a logical aspect of database design whereas indexes are a physical implementation feature. The proper separation of concerns is that the choice of keys is determined by logical, data integrity requirements whereas indexes exist entirely for the purpose of optimising performance and storage. One is not, and should not be, equivalent to the other.

Comment: As a struggling beginner of T-SQL, this is the best answer to start with. Other answers did not answer any question at all to me.

Answer (score 1):

From experience rather than theory I have discovered that it is important to use keys that are not shared by the user as "user data".  That is, user data, and keys should be different fields.

We had a database which used project codes.  The project codes were unique, never null, and had a business rule that once assigned would never be changed.  That makes it a candidate key.

However, if users see the project codes, look up file by project code and so forth, it's their data, and they will want to change business rules around the project code.

Our project codes were customer id followed by a dash and a sequence number to make it unique.  If a proposed project for one customer id ended up with a contract for a different customer id, the users wanted to change the project code.  If the user entered it with the wrong customer id, they wanted to change the project code.  Changing a primary key, and all the foreign keys referencing it is problematic.

That doesn't (seem to) answer the question *How can we decide on to go with Identity column or Primary Key?*

However, if you don't use customer data for a primary key, (as I have just argued you should not) then the primary key will need to be auto-generated, because you cannot not expect the user to enter it.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use a Primary Key it just makes your Database scalable. Use a GUID or a UUID or anything else that unique.